# How to print a string by checking the length as number of elements in list of dictionary

Tags: python

- My output is list of dictionary
- Generate a string according to length of query

List of dictionary is below

len(d) = 1

```
d = 
[{'name':'David'}]
```

Expected out is below

`{ "query" : "*David*","fields" : ["name"]}`

len(d) = 2

```
d = 
[{'name':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'}]
```

expected out is below

`{ "query": "*David*",  "fields": [ "name"]},{"query": "*Ansu*", "fields": [ "name"]}`

len(d) = 3

```
d = 
    [{'name':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'},{'name':'Rono'}]
```

expected out is below

`d  ={ "query": "*David*",  "fields": [ "name"]},{"query": "*Ansu*", "fields": [ "name"]},{"query": "*Rono*", "fields": [ "name"]}`

Q: My input can be any number of length. if len = n

Pseudo code

```
for in range(len(n)):
    print (f{})
```

Comment: How much have you tried? Is this assignment question? Please consider trying yourself first!

Comment: I suggest you break this problem into smaller parts. What are the steps you need to take to solve the problem? Try describing these steps in words.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice after all the process of data my output is list of dictionary. Generate a string according to length of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done according to the samples that have been provided.

```
final_list = []
d = [{'name':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'}]

for i in d:
  m = {
    'query':'',
    'fields':[],
  }
  for j in i.keys():
    m['query'] = '*'+i[j]+'*'
    m['fields'].append(j)
  final_list.append(m)

print(final_list)
```

outputs

```
[{'query': '*David*', 'fields': ['name']}, {'query': '*Ansu*', 'fields': ['name']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified my previous response with the below based on feedback received.

```
d = [{'name':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'},{'name':'Rono'}]
y = [{'query':'*'+i[j]+'*','fields':[j]} for i in d for j in i]
print (y)
```

Remember, you can also try to get the values 'David', 'Ansu', and 'Rono' into a list using

```
d = [{'name':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'},{'name':'Rono'}]
x = []
for i in range(len(d)): x.append(d[i]['name'])
```

Once you have the list of values from the list, you can just print the string in the way you want.

Comment: if my key `name` changed to any other lets say `name1` then your code wont work

Comment: means  d = [{'name1':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'},{'newname':'Rono'}]

Comment: sorry about that. I fixed the code. Here's the updated version

    d = [{'name':'David'},{'name':'Ansu'},{'name':'Rono'}]
    y = [{'query':'*'+i[j]+'*','fields':[j]} for i in d for j in i]
    print(y)